# Hyphenating Multiple Compound Adjectives With Common First Word

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation, compound-adjectives

I have a feeling this question has already been asked, but couldn't find it by searching. I found people asking about hyphenation of multiple compound adjectives with a common second word, but I'm wondering about hyphenation of multiple compound adjectives with a common first word.

What is the correct way to hyphenate a phrase like this, assuming that "sometimes" is modifying both "unreliable" and "inadequate?":

> sometimes unreliable and inadequate Internet service

Note that if style plays a role in your answer, I prefer American English and specifically Chicago style.

Comment: There's a [more recent similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405483/is-it-correct-to-say-inter-disciplinary-national-instead-of-interdisciplinar).

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly try the reverse of the use of same first-word compound adjectives (e.g., first- and second-generation immigrants) by doing this: sometimes-unreliable and -inadequate service. But that looks a bit odd and I would re-word if necessary.

Comment: If there was only one compound in each case you'd hyphenate **first-generation** but not **sometimes unreliable**. This must be the main reason for the difference, surely?