# Is it correct to say "inter- disciplinary/national" instead of "interdisciplinary and international"?

Tags: punctuation, dashes, slash

I'm trying to be more concise with my words. Does writing "inter- disciplinary/national" to describe to my educational background make sense? If not, what's a good alternative?

Comment: Nope.  Doing that would just draw attention to your difficulties with English.  And it's not really "more concise" -- conciseness is not about counting characters.

Answer (score 3):

First off, to follow a hyphen with a space where it's supposed to be joined to a word is just wrong.

That said, your proposed use is not easy to make sense of because, while *inter-disciplinary* might be hyphenated due to the word's complexity, *international* is not.

What you are doing is juxtaposing *inter-disciplinary* with *national,* not *international.*

You might get away with explicitly indicating that *national* is intended as a suffix by using a hyphen with that word: ***inter-disciplinary/-national;*** but it's clunky and the diverse nature of the education is far better expressed by using both *interdisciplinary* **and** *international* in full.